# Sum of angles of a triangle on a sphere

Tags: general-topology, geometry, spherical-geometry

What is the minimum and maximum of sum of angles of a [spherical triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTriangle.html)? Let us remove a constraint from spherical triangles: sides are not necessarily circular arcs. Then what will be the minimum and maximum of sum of angles of such triangles?

Comment: If the Earth is so big that locally it looks flat, then a triangle on the ground approximates on in the plane, with a sum of close to $180^\circ$.  It can be made as close as desired by making the triangle small enough: the smaller it is the flatter the Earth looks.  So that's the smallest, except that it's really an infimum rather than a minimum. $\qquad$

Comment: You really want to constraint the sides somehow. Otherwise the bounds are $0$ and $6\pi$ radians.

Comment: For a spherical triangle bounds are $\pi$ and $5 \pi$, am I right @EricTowers?

Comment: @EricTowers Indeed, at first it seems that the upper bound is $3\pi$ but in case of no constrains one can simply draw a "triangle" with virtualy zero angle sum, and then threat the outside as an inside of a second "triangle" with an angle sum of course $6\pi$

Comment: Yes, for a triangle whose sides are required to be arcs of great circles, the angle-sum $\Sigma$ satisfies $\pi<\Sigma<5\pi$. This corresponds to bounds on the area of such a triangle being $0<A<4\pi r^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A triangle with zero interior angle sum:

[image: A hyperbolic triangle]

(The horizontal line is not part of the triangle.  It's the line containing the diameters of the semicircles that are the edges of the triangle.  $IJK$ is a triangle *with straight edges* in a hyperbolic space.)

Although that triangle is drawn on the plane, it should be no great challenge to use it as a model to produce a triangle on the sphere with $0$ interior angle sum.  It's exterior is also a figure bounded by three sides and three vertices, so is also a triangle and the angle sum of its exterior is clearly $6\pi$.